# Can't install Titanium's app on my android 2.3.6 phone

Tags: android, titanium

I have been developing an app on Titanium, it runs well in the emulator (a Nexus 5) but I can't install it in my samsung GT-S5360L with Android 2.3.6 (I suspect it because android versions). Titanium recognize my phone.

Here the log:

```
(Other stuff)
[INFO] :   Making sure the adb server is running
[INFO] :   Installing apk: /home/username/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/appName/build/android/bin/appName.apk
[INFO] :   Installing app on device: GT-S5360L
[ERROR] :  Failed to install apk on "0123456789ABCDEF"
```

Please let me know if it is necessary some clarification. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: see [this answer](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/118650/specify-the-minimum-of-android-sdk) to provide min sdk support in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must   set the `(android:minSdkVersion)` to 2.3 in `Tiapp.xml`
so you can install you app in android 2.3.6 device

check this link for more info
[android sdks](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK)